Codable class for nested dictionary in Swift
I am currently trying to parse a nested dictionary response using Codable and trying to not use too much custom decoders.
JSON response looks similar to below:
{
  "id": "1234",
  "data": {
    "1": {
      "name": "foo1",
      "types": {
        "a": {
          "value": "bar1"
        },
        "b": {
          "value": "bar2"
        },
        "c": {
          "value": "bar3"
        }
      }
    },
    "2": {
      "name": "foo2",
      "types": {
        "d": {
          "value": "bar4"
        },
        "e": {
          "value": "bar5"
        },
        "f": {
          "value": "bar6"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Root Class
struct JSONResponse : Codable {
    let id : String?
    let data : Data?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

        case id = "id"
        case data = "data"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        id = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .id)
        data = try values.decodeIfPresent(Data.self, forKey: .data)
    }

}

Now the data class is where I would end up with many nested containers. Is there any better way to resolve this ?

I wouldn't name Data as such, as there is already Swift.Data, but you could use: let data: [String: Data] and Data being struct Data: Codable { let name: String; let types: [String: Typing] } and struct Typing: Codable { let value: String }

Are you responsible for the backend? If yes, send more decoding-friendly JSON, for example an array of objects containing dictionaries with fixed keys. If not, blame the service. Sending only dictionaries with dynamic keys fights the framework and JSONSerialization might be the better choice.

@Larme I have not tried that before. I thought for some reason dictionaries with custom objects are not decodable friendly.

@GoodSp33d It's more or less when you have Any that's not really compatible with Codable. There are a few workaround, but Codable is more targeted to "We know the model and it's predetermined". When you think in JSON Dictionary, we usually think of [String: Any], but at least in the sample you gave, Any is known.

Why is "many nested containers" undesirable? Your JSON has "many nested containers", so naturally that would be the case in Swift too. What is the desired result, that doesn't have "many nested containers"?
